# unwanted line break in paragraph

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

This is literally making me crazy...

I am working on a site with very simple CSS styling, and I have a bug I just can't solve.
This skitch note shows what I see in both Safari and Chrome (mac). I'm talking about the line break in the paragraph between "La" and "Vigne"
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s327/sh/940100eb-4610-4278-a6e2-61074a485203/01f2a5fc15a1ab03eff1b664ad28e2ca

The most crazy thing is, when I copy / paste all the HTML and CSS into a Fiddle, it works perfectly well : http://jsfiddle.net/7YX8v/

```
article {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1400px;
    padding:30px;
    font-size:1.8em;
    color: #fff;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f9f8f7, #b2aba4);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      text-align:left;
}

article img {
    width:25%;
    margin:0 12.5% 0 12.5%;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    float:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}

article p {
    width:40%;
    margin:0 0 0 50%;
    padding:20px 0 20px 0;
    display:block;
    height:auto;
}
```

I just can't figure out what the problem is. If anyone has an idea, I'm all ears !

Comment: Without seeing your whole code / live demo it's hard to tell, but from the snippet in jsfiddle I can see `wrap: word-break;` is invalid. It should be `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: A question should contain sufficient code (including HTML) for reproducing the problem. Links are not enough.

Comment: The link points to a screenshot only, so we have *no* access to the actual code that produces the issue.

Comment: There's also a fiddle with both CSS and HTML code.
The mystery is why the same code on my website renders differently than on the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenue François. We're going to need to see the original source or more information here. Also, why the inline style of width 330px in the fiddle? In the code you post it seems you are only working with percentages.

EDIT: I played around with your fiddle and there were some strange things going on in the CSS that may be causing troubles.

1. No need to display:block the image, it's the default behavior for images
2. Padding on the article will make the article 60px wider than the screen-width
3. text-align:center on the article is redundant, as it is inherited from the body
4. Why text-align:center only to override it with text-align:left in the body? Both can removed -> text align-center:left is default
5. The paragraph styling is strange

   ```
   article p {
       /* redundant */
       width:40%;
       /* redundant */
       margin:0 0 0 50%;

       /* add the 30px you threw on the article to the sides of 
   the paragraph instead */
       padding:20px 30px;

       /* redundant */
       display:block;
       /* redundant */
       vertical-align:top;
   }
   ```

   I suggest you let the paragraph flow normally according to default CSS behavior. Remember, you are floating the image, which means the browser is told the paragraph should flow around the block of the image, there's usually no need to specify width and make it a block, the browser should do an excellent job of figuring all that out by itself.

I cleaned up the fiddle, available here: http://jsfiddle.net/7YX8v/8/

My guess is this is why you are getting strange results

Comment: Thanks for your answer CervEd !
I reopened my project this morning, and though I didn't change anything, the problem disappeared. Maybe I had cache issues with safari...

Your solution is fine, but what should I change if I want all the text to be aligned on the right of the image, even when it goes further down ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to clean your code a bit to get what I think you want to do:

```
article img {
    width:330px;
    float:left;
}

article p {
    margin:0px 0px 20px 360px;
}
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/7YX8v/5/

Comment: Thank you jthe, but I need dimensions in % since I'd like the content to adapt to the window size.

Comment: Ok so just replace the fixed size by percentage but anyway you can use this to have your text always in the right of the image even when it goes further down.